# onReceive() is not always called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

For some reason, the `onReceive()` method of my `BroadcastReceiver` class is not always called. It is usually called, but sometimes it is not.

More specifically, I am receiving `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE`. Most of the time, when a call comes in, the `onRecieve()` method is called as it should be for changes to RINGING, IDLE, and OFFHOOK.  However, there are some occasion when the method is NOT called for RINGING (when a call is incoming) but it is still called for IDLE (when I hang up the call).

From the manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".CallReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

The onReceive method itself is pretty simple:

```
public void onReceive(Context voCtx, Intent voIntent)
{
    Log(voCtx, "onReceive: " + voIntent.getAction());
    if(voIntent.getAction().equals(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED))
    {
        HandleCallStateChanged(voCtx, voIntent);
    }
}
```

Log just outputs to my log file, so I can see what's happening.  I'm not sure why `onReceive()` is only called sometimes. Could some other app be intercepting the broadcasts and cancelling them before my app gets them?

Comment: You should add permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />`

Comment: Check this link 
https://www.studytutorial.in/android-phonestatelistener-phone-call-broadcast-receiver-tutorial

Comment: I have this in my manifest.  I just forgot to post it.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Android now has a feature of Doze and App standby. So, if your app enters this mode, then your `BroadcastReceiver` will not trigger.

To allow your receiver to get triggered you can make use of `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS` permission . This way your app will be excluded from the battery optimisation process.

**CAUTION: GOOGLE MAY BAN YOUR APP IF YOU DON'T USE THIS PERMISSION WITH CARE**

Comment: I used an Android emulator and debugger to test my app with Doze mode (<https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html>) and everything worked fine.  Then I accessed the developer settings on my actual phone and manually put my app into an inactive state (which I've been led to believe puts it in App Standby) and everything worked fine then too.

Comment: I don't know what conditions cause `onReceive()` not to be called.  I cannot replicate it in the emulator and I cannot deliberatly replicate it on my phone.  The problem just seems to occur at times over prolonged use of the app on my phone.  After reading about App Standby, I really thought that would turn out to be the cause.  Perhaps there was something wrong with the way I tested it.

Comment: Did you test with `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMISATIONS` ?

Comment: Not yet.  I wanted to confirm that App Standby was the problem first, but I do intent to test `REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMISATIONS` eventually.  The problem is so intermittent that the only way to confirm that any solution is working (without first determining the cause of the problem) is to just use my phone for a few weeks and see what happens.  Given that, I'd prefer to ascertain the cause first, but if I can't, and it's looking like I can't, then I'll just have to test your solution for a few weeks and see what happens.

Comment: The problem happened today and while I was testing some things I came across something that seems like it might be specific to Samsung phones.  Under the battery settings, there is an "App power monitor" (in addition to the normal Battery Optimization stuff).  Apparently, this App power monitor can put apps to "sleep" (which seems different from App Standby).  Setting my app as an "Unmonitored app" seemed to make my problem go away for the moment.

Comment: It's been a month now and the problem has not recurred.  It seems the Samsung App Power Monitor was the issue.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is specific to Samsung phones. Under the battery settings, there is an "App power monitor" (in addition to the normal Battery Optimization stuff). This App power monitor can put apps to "sleep" (which is different from App Standby). Setting my app as an "Unmonitored app" seems to have fixed my problem.

Comment: Hi It's been two months since this answer. Can you confirm that adding the application to unmonitored apps helped? I'm having the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't had a problem since setting the app as unmonitored.